# Does convex set in Alexandrov space has positive reach?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a metric space, $A$ a subset of $M$. The reach (defined by Federer) of $A$ in $M$ is the largest $r_0\ge 0$ such that if $x\in M$ and the $d(x, A)< r_0$, then $A$ contains a unique point nearest to $x$.
My question is whether a convex subset in Alexandrov space always has positive reach? In Riemannian manifold there is a convex radius which shows the positivity of reach. (We will assume the subset to be compact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no".

Say consider the doubling $M$ of plane region $F=\{y\ge x^2\}$.
$M$ is known to be an Alexandrov space.

Let $A\subset M$ is the doubling of the intersection of $F$ with the disc with center $(0,-1)$ passing through $(1,1)$.
Note that $A$ is convex but all the points on the parabola have two minimizing geodesics to $A$ (one in each of to copies of $F$ in $M$).

[image]

So $A$ has zero reach.

Comment: @Anton, It seems that although there are two geodesics but they are actually connecting  $p$ to the same point $(1, 1)$ on the boundary of $A$, right? Which by definition is of positive reach.

Comment: @Ralph: no, see the picture.

Comment: @Anton, Question: $F$ is doubled to get $M$, are you saying $A$ is a doubled (portion of) disk?, if so $A\nsubseteq M$.

Comment: @horse, $A$ is not glued along the top portion.